# Rectifiable Curves: countably many and visualizing them

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, curves, supremum-and-infimum, visualization

The following question is based on Stein-Shakarchi's Real Analysis, proof of Prop 4.7 on page 140, which deals with the Minkowski content of a curve. The parts I am stuck on in the proof, however, deal more with things like continuity and visualizing a curve.

[image]

[image]